# Terminal in virtual environment says 'dpkg: no packages found matching libxml2-dev(for example)' and these packages are installed

Tags: python, linux, binary, virtualenv, angr

I am trying to work with angr multi-architecture binary analysis platform, I am following the [documentation](https://docs.angr.io/INSTALL.html) on its webpage, and I am installing the platform's developer edition through git. I have no problems cloning the repository and creating the virtual environment, but when I try to set up angr inside the virtual environment running *./setup.sh* on the terminal, I get the following message:

[image: error]

I am pretty sure all these packages are installed, when I run an aptitude search to check if these packages are installed packages are shown as installed.

[image]

NOTE: It is my first time working with python and virtual environments, sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: From reading `setup.sh`, some of these packages are not installed.

Comment: @Velkan Please read well the whole post.

Comment: Please, check every package.

Comment: @Velkan I checked every package with aptitude search and there are results for every of them.

Comment: @Velkan I am working on a virtual environment, so virtualenvwrapper is installed, on the contrary, I would not be able to create the virtual environment.

Comment: What about 'dpkg: no packages found matching libxml2-dev' and a dozen of others? `dpkg --get-selections libxml2-dev`

Comment: Also, you can actually run `./setup.sh -i`. It will install dependencies by itself, hopefully.